# Selecting a radio button to display a popup and stay selected as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two radio buttons as following in a form

```
<input type="radio" name="advice" value="office" class="office">
<input type="radio" name="advice" value="phone">
```

When i select the `office` radio button, I want to display a popup. This is working perfectly fine using the following script

```
$(function () {
    $('.office').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var dialog = $('<p>Please be aware that our office is located at ABC.</p>').dialog({
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    dialog.dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The problem I am having is although on selecting the radio button `office` popup appears but the radio button is actually not getting selected. The DOT in radio button remains inside the other radio button, so on submitting the form i keep getting the value of same radio button.

I will really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use **[change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/)**  by this when radio box change then dialog box open  but 
now when you click dialog box open but not selected due to it's not open on change event

```
$(function () {
    $('.office').change(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var dialog = $('<p>Please be aware that our office is located at ABC.</p>').dialog({
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    dialog.dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice one great solution

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `e.preventDefault()`, [**Here's a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/4xJ7J/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `change` at the place of `click`

or you just remove `e.preventDefault();`

```
$(function () {
  $('.office').change(function (e) {
    var dialog = $('<p>Please be aware that our office is located at ABC.</p>').dialog({
      buttons: {
       "Close": function () {
         dialog.dialog('close');
       }
     }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use jQuery [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event, no need to bother about it.

```
$('.office').change(function (e) {
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use change function. Click won't work in this scenario.

Check this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3fJk2/)**

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="advice" value="office" class="office">Office
<input type="radio" name="advice" value="phone" class="phone">Phone
<div id="dialog_content"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    var dialog = $('#dialog_content').dialog({
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    dialog.dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });

         dialog.dialog('close');

    $('.office').change(function (e) {
        dialog.dialog('close');
        $('#dialog_content').html('<p>Please be aware that our office is located at ABC.</p>');
        dialog.dialog('open');
    });

    $('.phone').change(function (e) {
        dialog.dialog('close');
        $('#dialog_content').html('<p>This is Phone dialog.</p>');
        dialog.dialog('open');
    });
});
```